# Print out last amount

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble with xml and xsl. This is what I have in my task:

```
<InvoiceList>
   <Invoice>
      <ItemId>111-111</ItemId>
      <InvoiceAmount>6160</InvoiceAmount>
   </Invoice>
   <Invoice>
      <ItemId>222-222</ItemId>
      <InvoiceAmount>4840</InvoiceAmount>
   </Invoice>
</InvoiceList>
```

When I use this instance in xsl:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(//Task/InvoiceList/Invoice[ItemId]/InvoiceAmount, '###,###.00')"/>
```

On printout I get 6,160.00 but I want to print out second amount 4840

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Regards,
Zoran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `last()` function here...

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="format-number((//Task/InvoiceList/Invoice[ItemId]/InvoiceAmount)[last()], '###,###.00')"/>
```

Note, if you do this (notice the lack of brackets)...

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="format-number(//Task/InvoiceList/Invoice[ItemId]/InvoiceAmount[last()], '###,###.00')"/>
```

Then for every `Invoice` item in the document, it will find the last child `InvoiceAmount` under each such element. (Note that in XSLT 1.0, when you select multiple nodes, the `format-number` function will only print the first one. If you tried the same in XSLT 2.0, it would get an error).